# Outlook add-in: How to validate body message on composing every 3 seconds?

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to do validation to Outlook body message on composing,
i found the demo in github:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send.git

but i need to do an auto validation each 3 seconds, or each space tab click 
(The github demo triggers only when clicking "send")

this is what i got for now, How do i improve it for my needs?

**JS:**

```
var mailboxItem;

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}
function validateBody(event) {
    mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, validatioFunction);
}
```

**XML:**

```
   <Hosts>
    <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
      <DesktopFormFactor>
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
          <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
        </ExtensionPoint>
      </DesktopFormFactor>
    </Host>
  </Hosts>
```

Answer (score 0):

Events (ItemSend) extension point is not the appropriate for long running tasks, you can add a MessageComposeCommandSurface extension point to your add-in and keep polling for body change.

Outlook does not provide an API to listen on body changed event. We track feature requests on [our user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins).
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the [existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/38506099-add-api-to-invoke-the-text-changed-event-on-the-me). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Useful links:
[Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=yeomangenerator)

Comment: Thanx, but maybe i can do an interval each 3 seconds to get the body of the email? How can i perform it?

Comment: Yes, you can create an add-in command with the [FunctionFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-5-add-the-functionfile-element) element to execute JS in the background. You can use this to call body.getAsync() every 3 seconds. However, do note that this would only work as long as the add-in is running, which needs the user to click on the button.

Comment: So there is no way to trigger the FunctionFile without the user clicking buttons?
I need the functionality to validate body message in the background without user interference.

Comment: As already mentioned, you'll need the addin to be in running state to (which needs the user to click on the button) call body.getAsync()  every 3 seconds.

Comment: So is there a way to trigger event when user clicks the "New message" button?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, we do not have any triggers for the "New message" button, but if you could state your use case and raise a request on the user-voice page posted, we can consider the requests when we go through our planning process.